# Angular product update from 12 to 16 failed with missing peer dependencies error

Tags: angular, migration

I am working on upgrading the Angular version from 12 to 16.

Angular migration is failing for missing peer dependencies error if I don't specify the `--force` with the `ng update` command.

I executed `ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --force` command for migrating the application from 12 to 16.

Is it a good practice to use `--force` with the `ng` command?

After the successful migration, I will need to deploy the changes on the server.

I will also need to execute `--force` on the server. Is it a good practice?

If it is not a good practice, then we need help with the Angular migration failing issue solution.

I executed the following commands for completing the Angular version migration without issues.

1. ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --force
2. ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14 --force
3. ng update @angular/core@15.2.10 @angular/cli@15.2.10 --force
4. ng update @angular/core@16.2.11 @angular/cli@16.2.11
5. npm install --force

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `--force` option should only be used if you know its only a peer dependency warning with an older package that's still compatible with an updated version of Angular.

Even after you upgrade the packages that way, you may still run into peer dependency errors when using `npm install`. In that case, you want to add a `.npmrc` file at the root of your project with the `legacy-peer-deps=true` flag in it. This bypasses the peer dependency errors.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps

Ultimately, you still need to validate that the packages you depend on work with the latest version of Angular you're upgrading to. Upgrading one major at a time is always recommended.

Comment: Completed the Angular Framework upgrade as per the Angular official website update guide and wrote an article for that. Article link: https://medium.com/@mahalakshmi.veeraraj.btech/angular-framework-update-from-12-to-13-in-the-project-c5179a1d5c8c.